# Telling gdal_polygonize.py how to interpret colors / what does the `DN` field mean

Tags: gdal, vectorization

I have lots of raster files I am converting to polys with `gdal_polygonize.py`. All these images have a consistent palette which I'd like to map to an attribute in the resulting polygons.

On most images, the output `DN` field is mapping consistently to the color values in the input rasters, however on one image it seems like the `DN` value is flipped.

I think it has something to do in which order the colors appear first in the image, because on that image, light orange appears first, then yellow and then orange (usually the order is orange, light orange, yellow and sometimes green).

#### What I've tried to fix it

1. The original input images are colored with a gradient from orange to green. I thought I could fix this by mapping these colors to a single band (I chose red) assigning the values #010000 through #040000 using `convert ... -fill #010000 -solid -opaque #ff9900 ...` and so on. This doesn't change the result though.
2. (in addition to 1) I'm already using `gdal_edit.py` to define the images bounding box, so additionally I've passed the flag `-colorinterp_1 red` to it and `-band 1` to `gdal_polygonize.py`. This hasn't worked either.

#### Question

How do I tell `gdal_polygonize.py` how to interpret the colors in my raster files?

#### Images

[image: failing raster]

This is the raster that fails to receive the correct values for the colors.

Orange = 3, light orange = 1, yellow = 2

---

[image: working raster]

This is an example raster that works as I expect.

Orange = 1, light orange = 2, yellow = 3

---

[image: stretched failing raster after mapping palette to red channel]

How the failing raster looks after mapping the palette to the red channel with `convert` (stretched with curves so it's not all black)